# How to view output if collection is passed as out parameter in Oracle PL/SQL?

Tags: oracle, plsql

**Collection**

```
create type p_tab_type is table of varchar2(30) ;
```

**Procedure**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE p_jin_proc(p_dept   IN  emp.mgr%TYPE,
                                       name_tab OUT p_tab_type) IS
  BEGIN

    SELECT empno BULK COLLECT INTO name_tab
    FROM emp
    WHERE mgr = p_dept;

  END p_jin_proc;
```

I am unable to get the values out of name_tab collection in output window.

Comment: Can you please show us, how you try to see/print the output?

Answer (score 3):

From SQL Developer or SQL*Plus you can do this:

```
var rc refcursor

declare
  name_tab p_tab_type;
begin
  p_jin_proc(1, name_tab);
  open :rc for select * from table(name_tab);
end;
/

print rc
```

Executing that as a script in SQL Developer will show the resulsts in the Script Output window. Not entirely sure if that's what you were referring to.

[`variable`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve050.htm) declares a bind variable ref cursor called `rc`. The anonymous block calls your procedure and opens that bind variable with the values from the collection. Finally [`print`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve031.htm) displays the contents of the bind variable.

You could also write a wrapper block that calls your procedure then steps through the collection and displays each value with `dbms_output`, as long as your client is displaying that (as Wernfried shows).

```
set serveroutput on
declare
  name_tab p_tab_type;
begin
  p_jin_proc(1, name_tab);
  for i in name_tab.first..name_tab.last loop
    dbms_output.put_line(name_tab(i));
  end loop;
end;
/
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to loop over your collection:

```
select empno bulk collect into name_tab from emp where mgr = p_dept;

for i in name_tab.first..name_tab.last loop
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(name_tab(i));
end loop;
```